# R: sequentially applying an arbitrarty list of functions with arguments to a matrix

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of filtering functions `f1,f2,f3,f4,....` which take a matrix `m` and a number of options as input and return a subset of the rows of matrix as output. Now I would like to be able to define in an orderly way some meta-filtering function settings `metaf1, metaf2, metaf3,...` which would specify the sequential application of a specified nr of filtering functions, e.g. first `f2` and then `f3`, using given options for each. I would like to store these filtering settings in a list of say class `"metafiltering"`, and then have another function apply the filtering steps specified in a given `metafiltering` object. My idea would be able to in this way allow filtering settings to be stored and applied in an orderly way. How would I achieve this in the most elegant way in R? Or is there perhaps other convenient methods to achieve something like this?

EDIT: to give an example, say I have matrix

```
m=replicate(10, rnorm(20))
```

and filtering functions (these are just examples, obviously mine are more complicated :-) )

```
f1=function(m,opt1,opt2) { 
return(m[(m[,2]>opt1)&(m[,1]>opt2),])
}
f2=function(m,opt1) { 
return(m[(m[,3]>opt1),])
}
```

And I have defined the following `metafiltering` settings of specific class which would specify two functions which would have to be applied sequentially to matrix m

```
metafilterfuncs=list(fun1=f1(opt1=0.1,opt2=0.2),fun2=f2(opt1=0.5))
class("metafilterfuncs")="metafiltering"
```

The question I have then is how I could apply the filtering steps of an arbitrary `metafiltering` function object to given matrix m using the specified functions and settings?

Comment: A reproducible example would improve your question.

Comment: @Roland I've just made it more specific - hope this helps to understand my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**pryr**](https://github.com/hadley/pryr) has a function, `compose`, like what you need, but it doesn't quite cut it. The compose function requires the functions to be given one by one, not in a list, and it cannot take arguments. It's also oddly placed in that package. A similar function can be found in **plyr**, namely *each*. But this function does not apply functions sequentially, but individually and outputs a named vector (list?).

agstudy provided a solution above, but it suffers from a problem: it can only take scalar arguments because it gives the arguments in a named vector. The solution to this is to use a named list instead. So, here's an improved function to replace the one in **pryr**.

```
compose2 = function(x, funcs, args, msg_intermediate = F) {
  if (length(funcs) != length(args)) stop("length of functions and arguments must match")
  for (i in seq_along(funcs)) {
    x = do.call(what = funcs[[i]], args = c(x, args[[i]]))
    if ((i != length(funcs)) && msg_intermediate) message(x)
  }
  x
}
```

`msg_intermediate` is a nice debugging argument that messages the intermediate results, so one can easier understand what happens.

Test it:

```
adder = function(x, n) x + n
compose2(0,
         funcs = list(adder, adder, adder),
         args = list(list(n = 1), list(n = 2), list(n = 3)),
         msg_intermediate = T
         )
```

Outputs:

```
1
3
[1] 6
```

This is what you get when you take 0, then add 1 (=1), then add 2 (=3), then add 3 (=6).

The `args` argument for compose2 takes a list of lists, so that one can supply non-scalar function arguments. Here's an example:

```
add_div = function(x, n, d) (x + n) / d
compose2(0,
         funcs = list(add_div, add_div, add_div),
         args = list(list(n = 1, d = 1), list(n = 2, d = 2), list(n = 3, d = 3)),
         msg_intermediate = T
)
```

Output:

```
1
1.5
[1] 1.5
```

Which is what you get when you take 0, add 1, divide by 1 (=1), then take 1, add 2 then divide by 2 (=1.5), then take 1.5, add 3 and then divide by 3 (=1.5).

Comment: I note one disadvantage with this solution relative to `pryr::compose`. This function applies the function to the object instead of returning a combined function. This is a problem in some contexts. It can be fixed however, but I don't have time right now. Perhaps someone can supply the improved solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

You define a sort of functions pieplines where you give a priority for each function.

```
pipelines <- c(f1=100,f2=300,f3=200)
```

I define 3 dummy functions here for test:

```
f1 <- function(m,a) m + a
f2 <- function(m,b) m + b
f3 <- function(m,c) m + c
```

For each function , you store the argument in another list :

```
args <- list(f1=c(a=1),f2=c(b=2),f3=c(c=3))
```

Then you apply your functions :

```
m <- matrix(1:2,ncol=2)
for (func in names(pipelines[order(pipelines)]))
{
  m <- do.call(func,list(m,args[[func]]))
}
```

Comment: Ha many thanks for this - that's splendid! It's the do.call bit I didn't know about - thx for your help!!

Comment: And would it also be possible by any chance to pass the arguments of the functions directly in the pipelines vector, as in pipelines <- c(f1(a=1),f2(b=2),f3(c=3)), where f1 would have to applied first, then f2 and then f3?